# can not change generated table row color

Tags: android

When I create table row with xml I can change its color onclick. This is the way I use:

```
Resources resource = context.getResources();
row.setBackgroundColor(resource .getColor(R.color.green));
```

But when I generate the tablerow by code it does not change....

this is the code

```
row = new TableRow(dialog.getContext());
            row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            row.setPadding(dpToPx(5), dpToPx(5), dpToPx(5), dpToPx(5));

            text = new TextView(dialog.getContext());
            text.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            text.setText(patients.get(1).getPatientInternalId());
            text.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
            text.setId(i);

            TableRow.LayoutParams l1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            l1.setMargins(dpToPx(2), 0, 0, 0);
            text.setLayoutParams(l1);
            row.addView(text);

            text = new TextView(dialog.getContext());
            text.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            text.setText(patients.get(1).getPatientStudyId());
            text.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
            TableRow.LayoutParams l2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            l2.setMargins(dpToPx(5), 0, 0, 0);
            text.setLayoutParams(l2);
            row.addView(text);

            text = new TextView(dialog.getContext());
            text.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            text.setText(patients.get(1).getPatientInitials());
            text.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams l3 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            l3.setMargins(dpToPx(5), 0, 0, 0);
            text.setLayoutParams(l3);
            row.addView(text);

            text = new TextView(dialog.getContext());
            text.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            text.setText(patients.get(1).getEndTime());
            text.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams l4 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            l4.setMargins(dpToPx(5), 0, 0, 0);
            text.setLayoutParams(l4);
            row.addView(text);
            row.setClickable(true);

            row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       Resources resource = context.getResources();
                       row.setBackgroundColor(resource .getColor(R.color.green));
                       String a = ((TextView) row.getChildAt(0)).getText().toString();

                    }   
            });
            table.addView(row);
```

What is the problem ? How to change the color?

Comment: Check your third line -> row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); Try deleting this one.

Comment: And what ? I want to change color from onclick

Comment: You should try row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00")); instead row.setBackgroundColor(resource .getColor(R.color.green));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved !!!
the problem is that in onclick I should change the color usnig View v and nor row.Before it changes only the last row